# When I try to show all my vars with var_export( ) I get "Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string" Why?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of $_POST vars there, I know i do...

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    ${$key} = $value;

    echo(${$key});  // shows my vars .. yes I am going to sanitize them
};
```

but this..

```
$arr = var_export(array_diff(get_defined_vars(), array(array()))); 
print_r($arr);
```

gives me this message

```
Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string
```

What's going on here?

Comment: You aren't comparing the same things. get_defined_vars() returns all vars including any vars that you've defined to be a mysql connection. Are you expecting it to be the same as $_POST?

Comment: Do a `print_r( get_defined_vars() )` i'm suspecting there are other vars in your current scope that you are not taking into account.

Comment: omg man what's wrong with arrays? and I guess you gave somewhere in your code defined class of mysqli and trying to cast to string thats just wrong.. use arrays instead

Comment: @Cfreak - I didn't know what to expect. I'm troubleshooting (and inexperienced) and grabbed that from the PHP manual as a way to inspect all my vars.. I *would* expect my just declared vars to show up though, right?  I'm getting nothing! .. Although I have just echoed the vars out in the loop.

Comment: @Travesty3 - Thanks, but I know the post vars are there, since I have just woked with them and echoed them out in the foreach loop.  I just cant figure out why an INSERT isn't working and a wanted to see all the vars I was dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

MySQLi object instances and their associated result resources differ from regular objects whose properties are accessible. They represent the pipe or socket connection to your database, but are not serializable or directly representable as a string.

Any variable defined as a MySQLi connection resource will be returned by `get_defined_vars()` within the scope you call it.

Comment: So I guess the problem is that I *also* have a MySqQLI connection open in the present scope.  Maybe it just is choking on that and not getting to the others.  Thanks.

Comment: @K.K.Smith Yes, seems like that is what's happening here.